# Cash-flow prediction with machine learning

Tags: machine-learning

In our company we have huge incoming cash flows every day. Having a very good prediction on the incoming cash flows for the next working day would be for various reasons very useful.

As for the data: I have every incoming payment of the last 2 years. Every transaction has the actual day of the payment, the day on which we expected the payment to be received, the amount of money paid and an unique identifier for the user.

Of course we are only interested in the aggregated payments for one day. Due to our business we have a strong seasonality around the first working day of the month and an even bigger peak for the first working day of the year.

How would you try to model something like that? I know that LSTM is often used for time series forecasting, but would that also be a good idea to try that out in our case? Or from experience do you have an idea which other model might be suitable for this prediction task?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The preprocessing is actually already done. I just needed some idea with what to start.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29445)

Answer (score 2):

There are number of different time series forecasting algorithems other than LSTM's and other types of RNN's. In general the other methods that use statistical approaches take less time to run and are easier to understand.

From my experience some of the most important things is the data preprocessing rather than the algorithms (eg finding the seasonal period, finding how many seasonal periods there are identifying the trend to make a stationary series, removing outliers).
Once you have done this then you can evaluate different models with a test train split to see how they perform and choose the best model rather than starting off by choosing an algorithm.

You will probably find some interesting things will trying to account for the monthly seasonality due to the lengths of the months changing over time. One way to adjust for that is to use a dummy variable for the start of the month.

Depending on the problem there are a number of options.
Forecasting using statistical methods:

- Naive (uses the mean as the prediction)
- Seasonal Naive
- Arima (a Class of algorithms)
- Tbats

If there is a feature that is known in the forecasting window:

- Regressing

If there are multiple Features:

- Vector auto regression

I found [this](https://otexts.org/fpp2/) site very useful for learning what can be done with time series forecasting. (Its the html version of Forecasting: Principles and Practice Rob J Hyndman and George Athanasopoulos)